# Implementation of Specialized Templated Classes with Some Similar Features

Tags: c++, class, c++11, templates, enums

I would like to implement a class design that achieves the following architecture:

I would like to instantiate classes that describe the object "ReadoutChip" of 4 different flavours, defined by the enumeration:

```
enum Flavour {F1, F2, F3, F4};
```

so that a class of a given flavour can be achieved like:

> ReadoutChip<F1> Chip_1;

I have to specialize in some features of these flavour instantiations while keeping others the same. For example, all Chip objects (of all flavours) should have a private variable called `Threshold`; and I would like to have common public methods like `GetThreshold()`. However, these different flavours should have different attributes, which requires template specification. I have been unsuccessful in implementing something like this. Below is my attempt so far:

```
#include <iostream>

enum Flavour {F1, F2, F3, F4};
template <Flavour E, bool base = true> class ReadoutChip
{
        private:
                double Threshold = 1000;
        public:
                double GetThreshold();
};

template <> class ReadoutChip<Flavour::F1, true> : public ReadoutChip<Flavour::F1, false>
{
        public:
                ReadoutChip();
                ~ReadoutChip() = default;
                void SayHi();
};

ReadoutChip<Flavour::F1, true>::ReadoutChip() {std::cout << "Hi!" << std::endl;}

template <> double ReadoutChip<Flavour::F1, false>::GetThreshold() {return this->Threshold;}

int main()
{
        ReadoutChip<Flavour::F1> F_1;
        std::cout << F_1.GetThreshold() << std::endl;
        return 0;
}
```

This compiles successfully and somewhat gets the job done. Its only problems are that I have to copy the line:

```
template <> double ReadoutChip<Flavour::F1, false>::GetThreshold() {return this->Threshold;}
```

for each flavour, and apparently the line,

```
template <Flavour E> double ReadoutChip<E, true>::GetThreshold() {return this->Threshold;}
```

outputs a compilation error. Despite the partial success of this implementation, I would like to know if there is a way to achieve such a result without using the boolean variable base here, for the sake of C++ rigour.

Comment: Just drop the `bool base`, and create a single non-template class from which all specializations `ReadoutChip` will inherit. Does that work for you?

Comment: And using an inline definition, `double GetThreshold() { return Threshold; }` in the template, wouldn't work for what reason?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Many thanks for the reply! That is actually more straightforward :) I guess I thought like that because I started thinking with templates. But still, how can an implementation with templates be completed?

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Many thanks for the reply to you as well! inline works flawlessly and exactly as I want it to work!

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the question correctly I think a better fit here would be inheritance.

Have all of your "chip" variants derive from a common base `class`.
Stick all of your common code in the base `class`.

Take the example below, you can create as many "chip" variants as you'd like, just have them derive from your base `class`.

```cpp
class readout_chip_base
{
public:
    readout_chip_base(double threshold) noexcept
        : threshold_{threshold}
    {}

    double get_threshold() const noexcept {
        return threshold_;
    }

    virtual void take_reading() = 0;
    virtual ~readout_chip_base() = default;

protected:
    void update_threshold(double threshold) noexcept {
        threshold_ = threshold;
    }
private:
    double threshold_;
};

class f1_readout_chip : public readout_chip_base
{
public:
    f1_readout_chip() noexcept
        : readout_chip_base{42.01}
    {}

    void take_reading() override {
        update_threshold(104.23);
    }
};

int main() 
{
    f1_readout_chip f1{};  
    std::cout << f1.get_threshold() << '\n';  

    f1.take_reading();
    std::cout << f1.get_threshold() << '\n';  
}
```